# HTTPS GET call works on browser on 3rd party API but not through curl / fuel

Tags: http, curl, kotlin

I'm interested in retrieving information such as exchange rates from this API maintained by the Singapore government:

http://www.mas.gov.sg/Statistics/APIs/API-Documentation.aspx

For example, I can copy the following link to the browser to get end-of-month exchange rates:

https://eservices.mas.gov.sg/api/action/datastore/search.json?resource_id=10eafb90-11a2-4fbd-b7a7-ac15a42d60b6&limit=10&sort=end_of_month%20desc

But HTTP calls through curl or Kotlin Fuel don't work:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://eservices.mas.gov.sg/api/action/datastore/search.json?resource_id=10eafb90-11a2-4fbd-b7a7-ac15a42d60b6&limit=10&sort=end_of_month%20desc'
```

It returns a 404 page instead.

I've eliminated cookies, etc. from the browser call - it works regardless.

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Log out here http headers of http get and curl plZ

Comment: Request headers? As you see in curl I appended nothing to it and it didn't work. I also sent the request via Postman without any cookies, headers, etc - which worked as expected.

Comment: show me your kotlin code

Comment: is this in Android?

Comment: @Togrias I mean browsers request headers

Comment: Here's the headers of a browser request:

GET /api/action/datastore/search.json?resource_id=10eafb90-11a2-4fbd-b7a7-ac15a42d60b6&limit=10&sort=end_of_month%20desc HTTP/1.1
Host: eservices.mas.gov.sg
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

Comment: @I_of_T
Kotlin Code (doesn't work - returns 404 page, the same as curl):
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.httpGet

fun main (args: Array<String>) {
val query = "https://eservices.mas.gov.sg/api/action/datastore/search.json?resource_id=10eafb90-11a2-4fbd-b7a7-ac15a42d60b6&limit=10&sort=end_of_month%20desc"

query.httpGet().response { request, response, result -> print(response) }

}

Comment: use a different networking library, I found fuel quite tricky to use. And only got it working on an android app.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to Kotlin.

It seems that the remote app at `https://eservices.mas.gov.sg/api` treats different user agents differently, prohibiting any interactions from any CLI utils like curl or from your code. Try curl'ing it supplying different `User-Agent` headers and see what will happen. Even following bogus user agent works like a charm:

```
curl 'https://eservices.mas.gov.sg/api/action/datastore/search.json?resource_id=10eafb90-11a2-4fbd-b7a7-ac15a42d60b6&limit=10&sort=end_of_month%20desc' \
     -H'User-Agent: x____x' \
     -v
```

The same thing should work the same way from your code -- just send custom `User-Agent` header along with your requests. *And pray it will not be blacklisted someday*.

Comment: Yup, I think that did the trick.
Not sure why anyone would do that for a public api though. But I didn't get a response from their customer support.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using okHttp

```
fun calling() {
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://eservices.mas.gov.sg/api/action/datastore/search.json?resource_id=10eafb90-11a2-4fbd-b7a7-ac15a42d60b6&limit=10&sort=end_of_month%20desc")
            .get()
            .build()
    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
    println(response.code())
}
```